# React-Final-Form hidden field values

Tags: reactjs, react-final-form

I am transitioning from Redux-forms to react-final-forms, and I'm having trouble figuring out how to handle hidden form values. In redux-forms I could do something like
`this.props.change("createdBy", this.props.user.profile.username)` to set a hidden value, but that option doesn't appear to be an option in react-final-forms (or I am missing it).

I have thought that I could possibly use initialValues which works on new forms, but I run into trouble if I need to add additional values in a initial form. For example,

```
<Form
  onSubmit={ this.onSubmit }
  initialValues={
    item
      ? item
      : { createdBy: "Rachel", createdOn: new Date(), active: true }
  }
  render={({ handleSubmit, form, submitting, pristine, values }) => (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
...
```

where item might look like:

```
{
   code: "WTTC",
   description: "Welcome to the Club",
   active: true,
   createdBy: "Rachel",
   createdOn:"02/23/2021",
   modifiedBy: null,
   modifiedOn: null,
}
```

So if I set the initialValue of the form with the above item, I would like to also set modifiedBy and modifiedOn values which I use to do with `this.props.change("createdBy", this.props.user.profile.username)`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with this library at all, but from JS perspective you might achieve it by manipulating the initial value regarding the `item` object

```
initialValues={
          item
            ? {...item,createdBy: this.props.user.profile.username, createdOn: new Date()}
            : { createdBy: "Rachel", createdOn: new Date(), active: true }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
              <Field name="fieldName">
                {({input}) => (
                  <div>
                    <div className="field-wrapper">
                      <input {...input} type="hidden" name="fieldName" value="1"/>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                )}
              </Field>

props.form.getFieldState('fieldName').change(value);
```

form is the instance of final form from

```
 <Form
        onSubmit={onSubmit}
        subscription={{ submitting: true }}
        validate={validate}
        initialValues={initValues}
        render={({ handleSubmit, form, submitting, pristine, values }) => (
```